# Why didn't Lucifer save the priest?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucifer

In the ninth episode of the first season, Lucifer didn't save the priest and he died.

I assume he knew some magic. We saw in the first episode that he saved detective Decker. And we saw that Amenadiel saved another life (dirty cop - "Kevin Rankin").

Comment: You mean aside from Lucifer only having a fraction of his normal angelic power? And specifically only having evil powers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lucifer in the show, on the mortal plane, does not have his full range of powers. In the pilot episode, ***Pilot***, Delilah is shot in front of Lucifer, and he couldn't stop that. Later, Decker and Lucifer are shot at, and while Lucifer was unaffected, he couldn't stop Decker from being shot. He has to save her, the normal human way, by getting her to a hospital.

In ***A Priest Walks into a Bar***, Doyle shoots Conner, but Father Frank, in a spur of the moment, heroic, frankly godly manner, jumps in front of a bullet before anyone can react. Lucifer had no chance to stop it.

Remember, Lucifer has lost much of his power. He's lost his wings as well. He needed Amenadiel to try to get them back. At which point, Amenadiel, who is a fully powered Angel (supposedly) working on God's behalf, uses his powers to help. He slows down time for the humans, but not Lucifer, allowing Lucifer to walk around like normal. And when they fight because Lucifer burns the wings instead of letting Amenadiel take it, Amenadiel beats him easily. Of course, in this episode, Amenadiel resurrects the dirty cop Malcolm, with his powers.

**In short, Lucifer can't save anyone better than a normal human could. He's barely more powerful than the average person really. He doesn't have a full range of angelic powers.**

Considering the ending to the episode where:

> Amenadiel tells Malcolm he wants him to kill Lucifer. With a seemingly normal gun. Suggesting that Lucifer is on some levels mortal.

Comment: Lucifer being "on some levels mortal" isn't just suggested, it's explicitly stated in the episode where he's trying to retrieve his wings. He even tells Amenadiel that he's no longer impervious to bullets, who replies something along the lines of  "All I have to do is wait for some lowlife thug to shoot you." His powers at the current point of the series seem to be reduced to extraordinary strength (judging by how easily he lifts and throws people) and getting people to reveal their deepest desires.

Comment: What bothers me: he was on Earth 5 previous years and remained immortal

Comment: Lucifer's mortality is revealed to depend on the presence of Decker later in the series. He is clearly mortal when she is around but is still impervious to bullets when she is not.

Comment: In the Pilot Chloe is shot and it's implied that Lucifer saves her.   Maze even scolds him for it "what has gotten into you".    If I was to guess, it would depend on the wound and how close the person is to dying, in addition to his powers being somewhat muted.

Comment: @matt_black It's later explained that Lucifer's vulnerable around Decker by choice, and in later seasons he does not have that vulnerability.

Comment: @sandun subconscious placebo effect not choice.

Answer (score 2):

My theory on why Lucifer has suddenly become somewhat mortal after five years of being on earth is because he's near Cloe Decker, the one human who can resist his powers. She has some effect on his immorality. In fact I dont think he took her to a hospital in ep1 but did, in fact save her. By the time Father Frank was shot later in the series, Lucifers powers had deminished too far to save him hence his incredible anger when the father dies. As for the singer in ep1 she died instantly so had already "crossed over" (think the shooter who crashed but Lucifer was able to breifly talk to immediately after.) Even Maze states in the sneaker episode that "you're becoming mortal and we have to be careful until we find out why".